# Generating build meta data for a node/npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

Our team is using grunt and requirejs to build/optimize our application.  It would be nice if I could output some json w/ build date and an updated minor version number.  Seems like this would be a fairly common thing.  Anything out there that does this already?

Comment: You mean like a package.json? http://package.json.jit.su/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  [npm](https://npmjs.org/). The easiest way to create a package.json is with [npm init](https://npmjs.org/doc/init.html)